# Waiting for Event

Tags: java, android, webview, wait

I need to know how to wait for event to be triggered to set a Boolean. I got 2 classes simple classes: MainClass and Wait class:

```
    MainClass()
    {

        WebView wv; //It's already initialized from the xml and linked in the original code
        Wait waiting = new Wait();
        if(waiting(wv,URL))
        {
            wv.loadURL("javascript: ....");
        }

    }

    public Class Wait()
    {
        Boolean pageLoaded = false;
        Wait waiting = this;
        public boolean waitForPage(wv,URL)
        {

            wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
            {

                public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url )
                {
                    pageLoaded = true;
                    synchronized(waiting)
                    this.nothifyAll();

                }

            });

            wv.loadURL(URL);

            synchronized(this)  // --> End up in an Endless Loop
                this.wait();

            if(pageLoaded)
                return true;

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Does anybody know why it doesn't get synchronized and finally end up in an endless Loop? Maybe I use the wrong eventhandler?
The `this.wait();` seems to be like an `While(true)` verifying on a Boolean set by `NoifyAll()`. Please some Idea, how I can wait for these Events and Hold the program flow until the event is fired!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` in `synchronized(this)` inside the `onPageFinished()` method refers to the `WebViewClient` instance, while the `this` in `synchronized(this)` after `wv.loadURL(URL)` refers to the `Wait` instance.

Consider using the utilities in Android's [java.util.concurrent](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package

Comment: You are right, I copied the code bad, I deffinitly got the Wait Instance.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look to Link. But can't yet set your answer until i figured out if it's usefull to me and works.

Comment: Instead of synchronising on the class instance, synchronise on a monitor.  I don't recommend using Boolean because it immutable, instead use boolean[1].

Comment: So you mean I have to use `waiting.notifyAll()` instead of `this.notifyAll()`

Comment: Something like this: [link](https://gist.github.com/mitchwongho/ca308b8bcd99a7796bc3#file-java_conncurrency-java)